# How to save select multiple in database

Tags: java, html, multi-select, dto

this is my first time posting here. I have a question regarding on how to save the data coming from "html select multiple" into the database. I am using dto(data transfer object) to pass the value of the inputs in my form to the controller.

This is my HTML CODE:

```
<form:form id="user-form" action="/admin/users/add-user/add-success" commandName="addUser" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">
            <label class="text font-md">Profile Information</label>
        </legend>             

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Select Property <span class="important">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control custom-scroll" path="propertyList.propertyId" name="propertyId" id="propertyId" multiple>
                <c:forEach var="property" items="${property}">
                    <option value="${property.id}" data-value="${property.prtCompany.id}"><c:out value="${property.propertyName}"/></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <div class="note">
                <strong>Note:</strong> hold down the ctrl/cmd button to select multiple options.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

This is the code of my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users/add-user/add-success", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveAddUser(ModelMap mvc, @ModelAttribute("addUser") UserProfileDto userProfileDto, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServerException {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user-pages/user");

    userProfileDto.setAuditId(auditService.logAuditCreate().getId());
    userProfileDto = userProfileService.createUserProfile(userProfileDto);

    return mv;
}
```

This is my ServiceImpl:

```
public UserProfileDto createUserProfile(UserProfileDto userProfileDto) {
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
    userProfile = convertDtoToEntity(userProfile, userProfileDto);
    save(userProfile);
    return convertEntityToDto(userProfile);
}

protected UserProfile convertDtoToEntity(UserProfile userProfile, UserProfileDto dto) {

List<Property> propertyList = listUsersProperty(dto.getPropertyList());

userProfile.setProperty(propertyList);

return userProfile;
}

protected List<Property> listUsersProperty(List<PropertyDto> propertyDtoList) {
List<Property> propertyList = null;
for (PropertyDto propertyDto : propertyDtoList) {
    propertyList.add(entityManager.find(Property.class, propertyDto.getId()));
}
return propertyList;
}
```

This is the error:

```
19:37:37,543 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-40) UT005023: Exception handling request to /admin/users/add-user/add-success: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.altypaynet.crm.service.user.UserProfileServiceImpl.listUsersProperty(UserProfileServiceImpl.java:249)
at com.altypaynet.crm.service.user.UserProfileServiceImpl.convertDtoToEntity(UserProfileServiceImpl.java:261)
at com.altypaynet.crm.service.user.UserProfileServiceImpl.createUserProfile(UserProfileServiceImpl.java:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
... 91 more
```

And the DTO's,

UserProfileDto:

```
public class UserProfileDto extends UserBaseDto {

public UserProfileDto() {
}

private List<PropertyDto> propertyList;

public List<PropertyDto> getPropertyList() {
    return propertyList;
}

public void setPropertyList(List<PropertyDto> propertyList) {
    this.propertyList = propertyList;
}
}
```

PropertyDto:

```
public class PropertyDto extends CompanyDto {

public PropertyDto() {
}

private String propertyId;

private String propertyNo;

private String propertyName;

private String propertyType;

private Integer propertyUnits;

private Integer propertyFloors;

public String getPropertyId() {
    return propertyId;
}

public void setPropertyId(String propertyId) {
    this.propertyId = propertyId;
}

public String getPropertyNo() {
    return propertyNo;
}

public void setPropertyNo(String propertyNo) {
    this.propertyNo = propertyNo;
}

public String getPropertyName() {
    return propertyName;
}

public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
}

public String getPropertyType() {
    return propertyType;
}

public void setPropertyType(String propertyType) {
    this.propertyType = propertyType;
}

public Integer getPropertyUnits() {
    return propertyUnits;
}

public void setPropertyUnits(Integer propertyUnits) {
    this.propertyUnits = propertyUnits;
}

public Integer getPropertyFloors() {
    return propertyFloors;
}

public void setPropertyFloors(Integer propertyFloors) {
    this.propertyFloors = propertyFloors;
}
}
```

I already try searching about this but unfortunately there is no one that solve my problem. I hope you can help me guys. thanks.

note: Maybe some of you may ask what is the relation of the property to userprofile, I remove some of the code that are included in the codes, i just post the codes that is related to the error.

BIG NOTE: SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH. I DID MY BEST.

Comment: You never initialize your  "propertyList" to anything other than null (List<Property> propertyList = null;). So obviously you will get a NPE when trying to call propertyList.add(...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @911DidBush
List<Property> propertyList = null;
for (PropertyDto propertyDto : propertyDtoList) {
    propertyList.add(entityManager.find(Property.class, propertyDto.getId()));
}
return propertyList;

After it goes to for each it should not return null.

Comment: Please read the Question I linked. You cannot call propertyList.add as long as propertyList is set to null.

Comment: I also tried using List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<Property>();, do you have something to reccomend more? Anyways, thanks for  noticing my question.

Comment: Okay, if you initialize the propertyList like than you remove one source of a NPE. You should also check if the propertyDtoList is null before you iterate over it in a for loop, as using an enhanced for loop on a null object will also throw a NullPointerException. [if (propertyDtoList!=null) { for (PropertyDto propertyDto : propertyDtoList) {...}}]

Comment: @911DidBush Okay Bro, I'll try your suggestion. Many thanks.

Comment: Please Note that this will only help remove the NullPointerExceptions (Errors) that you are getting. There might still be logical errors in the code (Like for example the DTO not holding the values that it should).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UserProfileDto bean pass PropertyDto to the controller.

PropertyDto.getProperId() will give you all the selected values seprated by comma.
You are getting null pointer as dto.getPropertyList() does not contain any value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot do that, as I said on the last part of my question, there are other code that is included to that, I just remove it because the error I am getting is in the select multiple only

Comment: in other words, i have other inputs that needs to be bind in UserProfileDto, I just remove it the codes I give.

Comment: Then you at least need to add private String propertyId in your UserProfileDto alongwith getter setters.

Comment: Instead of private String propertyIid, I call the List of PropertyDto by initializing it.

Comment: this line:

private List<PropertyDto> propertyList;

Comment: This way you wont get the value of multi select. Try to understand basics of java framework. Name of your multi select  is propertyId, So you need to pass a bean that contains a variable with the same name. Only then you will be able to get the value.

Comment: Initializing arrayList wont solve your problem. Wont recieve multiselects value. PropertyList is an arraylist of type PropertyDto. It wont get multiselects value.